Using two different salts for one password ?(PBKDF2)
I wonder if using two salts for one password with PBKDF2 will actually increase security.
Enter the password: password
Enter the first salt: salt1
Enter the second salt: salt2
Enter the number of iterations: 600000
Standard PBKDF2 Derived Key (256 bits): 0d5a5a91c48f26569e9c0d9addf62c58b42890f4368c4abb500a2b46184e4017
Dual-Salt PBKDF2 Derived Key (256 bits): b6ff4e63bdeff7a55a05e84fab453d6281a6a1e42a51263b11eb743930e4bb38
Standard PBKDF2 Execution Time: 2.130392 seconds
Dual-Salt PBKDF2 Execution Time: 1.371493 seconds

Hiya & Welcome :-)   Do you believe that time >2 s isn't unacceptable to users?

How is using two salts more efficient? You haven't explained how the salts are being processed, and I don't see how that result is even possible.

Standard PBKDF2 can only take one salt input. If you're asking about a modified version of PBKDF2 that somehow takes two salts, you will first need to explain how you've modified it. Otherwise your question cannot be meaningfully answered.

PBKDF2 doesn't have an option for a second salt:
From the RFC:

 Input:          P          password, an octet string
                 S          salt, an octet string
                 c          iteration count, a positive integer
                 dkLen      intended length in octets of the derived
                             key, a positive integer, at most
                             (2^32 - 1) * hLen


So if you provide a second salt you need to specify how. Let's assume that you've concatenated both salt values for now.
If you combine them and retrieve both salt values then you basically have one salt again. The premise of the salt is that the salt value needs to be unique.
This uniqueness requirement is often accomplished by using a random number generator that output bytes. As we have to take the birthday bound into account that means having a 128 bit / 16 byte salt should be plenty. If fewer bytes are obtained or if the random number generator doesn't output "fully random" bytes then it may make sense to augment the value with another value so that the chance of collisions is lowered.
In other words, using a second salt is only more secure if the first salt may not be unique. In that case the combination of salts needs to be unique to fully avoid collisions.

Sometimes a pepper is used. A pepper is a secret similar to a secret key. The idea is that the pepper remains unknown to the adversary so that the result of the PBKDF2 cannot be calculated by an adversary. This, of course, requires that access to the pepper is restricted. In other words, it requires a secure storage facility separate from the salt and the password hash or ciphertext.

As for the benchmarks: you're probably using a JIT and the first run helps to optimize the algorithm. You'll probably see the same values after swapping the single and double salts. Without more knowledge of the system under test it is impossible to reliably see why one run finishes faster than the other.

It's unclear if they're talking about a pepper/secret key as well, which is supported in Argon2, for example.

@samuel-lucas6 Right you are, and I wanted to add that but forgot when writing the answer. I've added a section. Could you have a look to see if it is worded correctly?

That sounds ok. I'd say it is a secret key, although there's unfortunate naming overlap with something you have to rediscover. You could go into the different ways you can do peppering. a) pass a secret key to the password hashing algorithm, b) collision-resistant MAC the password before feeding the output to the password hashing algorithm, and c) encrypt the password hash with an AEAD or unauthenticated encryption algorithm. c) is arguably best for password hashing because it allows you to rotate the pepper without resetting passwords. a) is ideal for key derivation if available.

Something I don't think I've ever seen mentioned is how feeding all the inputs into the PBKDF is better than mixing some inputs (e.g., with a regular KDF) after deriving a key because it slows the attacker as much as possible. Otherwise, if the other input is low entropy, the attacker can derive the PBKDF output once (lots of delay) and brute force the non-PBKDF output much more quickly (no delay).

@samuel-lucas6 Ah, yes, good point. I'd generally just use just a label for key diversification in the KDF; you'd already have a key as IKM after all.
